How to Scroll to a Specific Item in a Dropdown When It's Not Visible?
I'm trying to implement a dropdown in my Flutter app such that when it opens, if the selected item is not visible, it automatically scrolls to make the item visible. However, I haven't been successful so far. Could someone please help me with this?
What I've Tried So Far:
Using ScrollController: I attempted to attach a ScrollController to the dropdown's list view and call animateTo to scroll to the selected item, but the scroll action didn't work as expected.
Programmatically Scrolling: Tried programmatically scrolling using various methods such as ScrollController.jumpTo and ScrollController.animateTo, but I couldn't get the item to be visible when the dropdown opens.
Adding Delay: Added delays using Future.delayed before attempting to scroll, thinking the list might not be fully rendered yet, but still no success.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
if (widget.isLoading) {
  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}

return DropdownSearch<String>(
  key: dropdownSearchKey,
  enabled: widget.isEnabled,
  items: widget.isEnabled ? itemLabels : [],
  selectedItem: selectedItem.isEmpty || !widget.isEnabled ? widget.hint : selectedItem,
  compareFn: (left, right) => left == right,
  onChanged: (selectedItem) {
    setState(() {
      this.selectedItem = selectedItem ?? '';
    });
    String? key = reverseMap[selectedItem ?? ''];
    if (key != null) {
      widget.onChanged({'key': key, 'value': selectedItem ?? ''});
    } else {
      widget.onChanged({'key': '', 'value': ''});
    }
  },
  dropdownButtonProps: DropdownButtonProps(
    icon: Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.6,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
        color: widget.isEnabled ? Theme.of(context).primary : Colors.grey, //icon
      ),
    ),
  ),
  popupProps: PopupProps.dialog(
    // scrollbarProps: ,
    showSelectedItems: true,

    showSearchBox: widget.isEnabled,
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    searchFieldProps: TextFieldProps(
      controller: editTextController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Search',
        labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(
              letterSpacing: 0.0,
              fontSize: 16.0,
              color: widget.isEnabled ? Theme.of(context).lightCoral : Colors.grey,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () {
            if (editTextController.text.isEmpty) {
              dropdownSearchKey.currentState?.closeDropDownSearch();
              editTextController.clear();
              _clearSelection();
              widget.onClear();
            } else {
              editTextController.clear();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    dialogProps: DialogProps(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (context, item, isSelected) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8), //selecao
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isSelected ? Theme.of(context).secondary : Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: Text(
          item,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(
                letterSpacing: 0.1,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: isSelected ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                // color: Theme.of(context).primary,
                color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Theme.of(context).primary,
              ),
        ),
      );
    },
    onDismissed: () {
      editTextController.clear();
    },
    containerBuilder: (context, popupWidget) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: popupWidget),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 8.0),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                dropdownSearchKey.currentState?.closeDropDownSearch();
                editTextController.clear();
                _clearSelection();
                widget.onClear();
              },
              child: Text("Cancel"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
  dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
    dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: widget.isEnabled ? Theme.of(context).primary : Colors.grey,
      ),
    ),
    baseStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(
          letterSpacing: 0.0,
          fontSize: 16.0,
          color: widget.isEnabled ? Theme.of(context).primary : Colors.grey,
        ),
  ),
);
}


I got similar probleam couple days ago.
It's a IM Chat Page needs to scroll to end when message was loaded.
I first tried delay 50ms, I belive it's not enough for flutter rendering all Message widget, always stop in somewhere middle of Listview.
when the delay is over 300ms, the scrollController.animateTo always take me to the end of Listview.
In Your situation it may works when your delay is longer.
void scroll2End() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {
      scrollController.animateTo(
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent * 2,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    });
  }


you accepted my answer, so delay works?

I also find out, scrollController.animateTo.duration will effect scroll to end action. duration too short will also cause stop in middle of ListView.builder. I got image and text in Listview.builder, with scrollController.animateTo.duration(seconds: 2) work fine.
